# Recursive Promise-based directory reading

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I have a library that scans a directory for files on a remote server. It returns a Promise like this:

```
client.scanRemoteDirectory(path)
  .then(files => { 

    console.log(files)

  })
```

I'm trying to write a recursive method to scan directories and subdirectories too. But I'm running into some async issues. My function is like this:

```
const scanDir(path) {

  // Scan the remote directory for files and sub-directories
  return client.scanRemoteDirectory(path)
    .then(files => {

      for (const file of files) {
        // If a sub-directory is found, scan it too
        if (file.type === 'directory') {

          return scanDir(file.path) // Recursive call

        }
      }
    })
}

const scanDir('some/path')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('done')
  })
```

This works however because of the `return` in front of the `scanDir()` recursive method call, this results in the method only scanning the first subdirectory in each directory and skipping the rest.

So for example if the structure is something like this:

```
/some/path
/some/path/dirA
/some/path/dirA/subdirA
/some/path/dirB
/some/path/dirB/subdirB
```

The above method will only scan:

```
/some/path
/some/path/dirA
/some/path/subdirA
```

It will skip `dirB` and it's children altogether since the method finds `dirA` first.

If I simply remove the `return` from the `return scanDir(...)` call, then it scans everything just fine. But then my final `console.log('done')` happens too soon because it's async.

So how do I solve this problem? What is the proper recursive Promise approach where I can still preserve async but also scan every subdirectory recursively?

Comment: Personally, I would approach the issue using `promise.all` instead of the foreach loop. In a nutshell, create an array of promises, loop the array of "files", push each promise to the array and call `promise.all`. In this way, regardless how many promises are recursively chained, the parent promise will be resolved only when children are. Also, I would manually handle a `Promise` object on top of the chain. Summarized, create the array, push the promises and do `return Promise.all(array)`. Beware though, since the response will be slightly different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[promise]%20recursive%20directory

Comment: Thanks for the call on the Promise.all. Returning the Promise.all instead of the Promise worked great. Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use `Promise.all` in this situation to run your 'sub' promises in parallel, for example:

```
function scanDir(path) {

    return client.scanRemoteDirectory(path)
        .then(all => {
            const files = all.where(file => file.type !== 'directory);
            const dirs = all.where(file => file.type === 'directory);
            return Promise.all(dirs.map(dir => scanDir(dir.path)) // Execute all 'sub' promises in parallel.
                .then(subFiles => {
                    return files.concat(subFiles);
                });
        });
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `reduce` function to run your 'sub' promises in sequence:

```
function scanDir(path) {

    return client.scanRemoteDirectory(path)
        .then(all => {
            const files = all.where(file => file.type !== 'directory);
            const dirs = all.where(file => file.type === 'directory);
            return dirs.reduce((prevPromise, dir) => { // Execute all 'sub' promises in sequence.
                    return prevPromise.then(output => {
                        return scanDir(dir.path)
                            .then(files => {
                                return output.concat(files);
                            });
                    });
                }, Promise.resolve(files));
        });
}
```

Async / await is definitely the easiest solution to read:

```
async function scanDir(path) {

    const output = [];
    const files = await client.scanRemoteDirectory(path);
    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.type !== 'directory') {
            output.push(file);
            continue;
        }

        const subFiles = await scanDir(file.path);
        output = output.concat(subFiles);       
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the `then` handler async so you can use `await` in the loop:

```
 const scanDir(path) {
  // Scan the remote directory for files and sub-directories
  return client.scanRemoteDirectory(path)
    .then(async files => {
       for (const file of files) {
          // If a sub-directory is found, scan it too
          if (file.type === 'directory') {
            await scanDir(file.path) // Recursive call
          }
      }
   })
 }
```

Comment: shouldn't it return the inner scanDir aswell? otherwise it will execute, but the response will be incorrect. That's an interesting approach though, didn't think about async / await.

Comment: If you're using `await` anyways, why all these `then` complications? Just do `files = await client.scanRemote(); for file of files etc`